# GCC, Unicode and __FUNCTION__

Tags: c++, gcc, unicode

I'm trying to make my project compile under GCC (Visual Studio compiles it flawlessly).

I have a custom assert function which throws a wstring message. A part of it is the _ _FUNCTION__ macro, which I "unicodize" using the WIDEN macro from MSDN

```
#define WIDEN2(x) L ## x
#define WIDEN(x) WIDEN2(x)
```

It compiles okay in MSVC, but it prints this in GCC:

```
error: ‘L__FUNCTION__’ was not declared in this scope
```

The only solution I could come with is to convert the contents of __FUNCTION __ to wstring on runtime using mbstowcs, but I would like to find a compile-time way to do it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should post your `__FUNCTION__` macro.

Comment: I thought it is automatically provided by the compiles, at least MSVS exposes it automatically. It won't even allow me go to the definition, so I don't know how it is defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GCC `__FUNCTION__` is a non-standard extension. To quote: [GCC Online Docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)

> In GCC 3.3 and earlier, in C only,
>   `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` were treated as string literals; they
>   could be used to initialize char
>   arrays, and they could be concatenated
>   with other string literals. GCC 3.4
>   and later treat them as variables,
>   like `__func__`. In C++, `__FUNCTION__`
>   and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` have always
>   been variables.

So adding L on the front of `__FUNCTION__` is just going to turn it into `L__FUNCTION__` which is probably undefined.

Comment: So I suppose the runtime conversion is the only way?

Comment: So I did it the runtime way. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Why the heck did they change that?? It seems to me always treating them as string literals would be a lot more helpful.